# AngularJS: Communication between directives and view updation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new in AngularJS. I search throw a lot of information and find some nice solution that should work for me (
[AngularJS communication between directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274563/angularjs-communication-between-directives)
). Code in first directive looks like that:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('myItem', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/item.html',
      restrict: 'C',
      controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $element.closest('.models-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
          $scope.$emit('model:updated', currentSlide);
        });
      }
 })
```

And in second:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('model', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/model.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function ($scope, $element) {
       $scope.$on('model:updated', function(e, data){
         $scope.item = data;
         console.log('scope',  $scope); // Here I see right value of item
       });
     });
    }
 });
```

But the problem is inside view/model.html:

```
<div class="left-block">
  <a class="back" href="#"></a>
  <div class="model-wrapper">
    <div class="front-view active">
      <img src="images/model.png"/>
      <img ng-if="item.frontImage" ng-src="{{ item.frontImage }}"/>
    </div>
    <a class="rotate"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't update. Is there are any mistakes in my code? How can I update my view?

Comment: Issues with scope have a lot to do with where they are in the DOM. It would be helpful to see more than just an image tag.  I don't even see any custom directives here...

Comment: @Balgor30 Thanks for your attention, I have updated the question.

Comment: try this. 
`$scope.$apply(function(){
          $scope.$emit('model:updated', currentSlide);
      });` or there `$scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.item = data;
         console.log('scope',  $scope);  }); // Here I see right value of item`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27915503/4365315

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev It's a pity but it's not working for me, I have tried both cases (

Comment: @Daria. Where is your my-item directive

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev my controller view that consist both directives : `<model></model>
<div class="right-block">

  <!-- clothes models -->
  <div class="clothes-models-wrapper">
    <div class="clothes-models">
      <div class="clothes-models-item-wrapper my-item" ng-repeat="item in ::clothesTypes">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emit '`model:updated`' inside `scope.$apply` in `myItem` directive since `afterChange` is a non-angular event

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear though, I will try to give some answer or hints for you consider:

First, the `$scope.$on` is not intended for you to pass data between different scopes. And why do you want to use the restriction of **C** for your `myItem` directive? how are you using the two directives `my-item` and `model`? where are they in your views?

You can build a **bi-directional binding** between directive and controller (or controller for another directive). You need to make an isolated scope in the directive `myItem`:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('myItem', function () {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/item.html',
      restrict: 'AEC',
      scope: {
          item: '='   //bi-directional binding
       },
      controller: function ($scope, $element) {
        $element.closest('.models-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
         // $scope.$emit('model:updated', currentSlide);
         $scope.item = currentSlide;
        });
      }
 })
```

In the directive template for your `model`, you can get the item

```
<my-item item="item"></my-item>
```